# anyway change the cursor "vertical line" instead of a box?

Tags: linux, xterm

Is there any way to change the cursor to a "vertical line" instead of a box in XTERM?

box:  ■

line: |

Comment: Where would you change it? tty, console, text editor, browser?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? For xterm, this is configurable with ~/.Xdefaults. Is this a plain vanilla xterm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think making the cursor a vertical line is possible in xterm. It is possible, however, to make it underlined. Just run `xterm -uc`.

It might be possible to do what you want using another terminal emulator. For example, I use Konsole and I can set the cursor shape to "Block", "I-Beam" and "Underline".

Comment: i wonder is there's some option for .Xdefaults =) thnx for this.

Answer (score 34):

It seems xterm has added support for the vertical bar or I-beam cursor.

You can change the cursor by inserting one of the following lines in your ~/.bashrc file (if you use bash):

```
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x30 q" # changes to blinking block
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x31 q" # changes to blinking block also
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x32 q" # changes to steady block
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x33 q" # changes to blinking underline
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x34 q" # changes to steady underline
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x35 q" # changes to blinking bar
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x36 q" # changes to steady bar
```

References:

- <strike>https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2248</strike>
- xterm changelog entry for [patch #282](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282):

> **Patch #282 - 2012/09/28**
>
> - extend DECSCUSR to provide a way to set the cursor to a vertical bar (patch by Paul Bolle).

- [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-SP-q.1D81)

  ```
      CSI Ps SP q  Set cursor style (DECSCUSR), VT520.
           Ps = 0  blinking block.
           Ps = 1  blinking block (default).
           Ps = 2  steady block.
           Ps = 3  blinking underline.
           Ps = 4  steady underline.
           Ps = 5  blinking bar,  xterm.
           Ps = 6  steady bar,  xterm.
  ```

Comment: And two more from me that are always demanded as well: `echo -ne "\x1b[?25l"` will __hide__ the cursor; `echo -ne "\x1b[?25h"` will __show__ the cursor again. For me this is essential when I want to "misuse" an `xterm` as a (pseudo-)write-only output console. __Besides__: Those lines seem to contain a little too much. A mere `echo -ne "\x1b[6 q"` will change to a steady bar. No idea what the "\x3" is meant for. Just omit it.

Comment: `echo -ne "\x1b[?25h"` fixed a problem for me. Worth making this into an alias and an approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Terminal emulator you're on.

Try looking at the menu:preferences:Window:cursortype if there's any.

I've seen changing the terminal cursor in Mac/Apple's terminal. Try to see in your linux box.