# Python curses draw nvim-style gui cursor vertical bar

Tags: curses, python-curses

How to draw the cursor as a vertical bar with python curses library?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17100535/9590859

There's no API in curses library for raw control sequences, just run:

```
def run_control_sequence(sequence):
    os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), bytes(sequence, 'utf-8'))

run_control_sequence('\x1b[\x36 q')
```

This solution is terminal dependent. The above control sequence is for xterm.

Comment: by running this function with given preferences for cursor it will update the cursor in the curses screen?